# Force squared form of a drawable in a weighted layout

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-xml, android-layout-weight

I have a linear layout with horizontal orientation and three buttons. In order to let them take up equally much space on each screen I set the width to `0dp` and the `layout_weight` to `1` in ordert to equalize the space they take up.

This works nice, except, that the height is not adjusted properly. My drawable is squared and while `layout_height="90dp"` looks fine on a Nexus 4, it can squeezed on a Nexus 7. How can I always get the right height in this situation?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/my_squared_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` attribute is **stretched**, by definition, and it doesn't use the `scaleType` modifier.
You better use the attribute `src`.

But you will need an **ImageButton** (or an ImageView, which is also clickable), instead of a Button.
So, the container will be evenly disposed in percentage, while the inner image will follow the `scaleType` modifier.

---

A button doesn't have the `src` attribute, which is what you need.
While the ImageButton (and ImageView) does.
And while using an ImageView as a button **may appear** strange, using an ImageButton is a very **common practice**

Comment: Oh, I did not know that button is unsuitable here, too bad. Yes, probably an image view, because I don't want the button base background. I find this a bit strange from a semantic point of view though.

Comment: A button doesn't have the `src` attribute, which is what you need. While the ImageButton (and ImageView) does. And while using an ImageView as a button **may appear** strange, using an ImageButton seems a very **common practice**

Comment: I was not aware that you can remove the default background with `android:background="@null"` from a `ImageButton`, then this is just fine. `ImageButton` makes semantically more sense than `ImageView`. Practical points aside, but it would seem more than a hack to use `ImageView`.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't. Often I use TextViews as buttons... ;) Say I need an xml drawable as the **transparent** background and a number in the middle that might change upon certain conditions. And have it disappear on click. This "hack" will do.